# Ration card for Schengen VISA application

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

I want to go to Germany for tourism. In the list of documents required for visa, ration card is mentioned in civil status proof. But in my ration card, the address written is not my present address but my village's address. Will there be any problem in it?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What do you mean by a ration card?  What's your citizenship?

Comment: @Karlson From the name, the country of Citizenship should be India and a [ration card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ration_card_(India)) in India is for subsidies. Hi Poonam, why don't you use your passport instead?

Comment: Do you have a driving license? Phone bill/electricity bill? These are also accepted as address proof other than your passport

Comment: Hi poonam. As Aditya already mentioned: Is "ration card" really explicity demanded without alternative (passport) in the visa application ? As German I would find it highly improbable that they really ask for it (but not entirely impossible...)

Comment: @ThorstenS. As someone would expect the passport is a valid residence proof in India and there is no requirement of a ration card. Electricity bill can also be used for the same purpose, but to me it seems that the passport is the easiest, so I'm not sure why the OP doesn't want to use the passport...

Answer (score 2):

From the question, it looks like you were asked a ration card for a civil status proof, and not as an address proof. However, the answers aim at the address proof.

In most cases, even for the Schengen visa when I applied for one, the passport works as both civil status and address proofs. However, if your passport also has a different address than your current once then you could use a BSNL phone bull or an electricity bill for address proofs. I am not sure if the Aadhar card and the voter's ID card work well as address proofs but they'd certainly be sufficient for the civil status proof. A PAN card is another document that works perfectly fine as a civil status proof.